# Android SQLite Database locked after crash during transaction

Tags: android, sqlite

If my application gets killed during a transaction (i.e. at position 1 in the source code below) the database is locked. The app was killed either using a task manager or terminating from within the debugger (I know that taskmanager should not be used and I know that it is my fault terminating the application at this stage ;-)) - but anyway, this can happen.

If I then try to restart the application, sqlite can not open the database, because it is locked (even after a restart of the device). On the filesystem there is the database file and a journal file. How can I restore the database and open it again?

```
  final SQLiteDatabase db = mDb.getDb();
  try {
       db.beginTransaction();
       //execute some updates (1)
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
   } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
   }
```

The database is accessed only by one thread at this time, and there is only one instance of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is to delete the journal file before opening the database...

Or handle the corrupt journal file somehow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've read somewhere in the sqlite documentation that deleting the journal file isn't a good solution, but I don't have a better idea, so that's what I'll probably do.